# Pure states as a proof entropy is emergent

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

Since the entropy of a pure state is zero, and assuming pure states are the most fundamental states i.e., there are no further levels of abstraction or building blocks, does this mean entropy is not on the same level of fundamentality as, say, energy, which is nonzero for pure states ?

Comment: You don’t need to think about any QM concepts such as pure states to understand that entropy emerges from a statistical approach to even classical mechanics.

Comment: how do you define "level of fundamentality" here?